# Simple adding don't work, timming issue

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

First there is this simple adder entity:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
           alu_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := (others => '0')
           );
end adder;

architecture Behavioral of adder is
  signal result_ext:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(32 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal result:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0)     := (others => '0');
begin

  process (a,b)
  begin
    result_ext <= std_logic_vector(signed('0' & a) + signed('0' & b));
    result     <= result_ext(result'left downto 0);

    alu_out <= result;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

And test bench:

```
-- TestBench Template 

  LIBRARY ieee;
  USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
  USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

  ENTITY testbench IS
  END testbench;

  ARCHITECTURE behavior OF testbench IS         

    signal a : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    signal b : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
    signal alu_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
  BEGIN
    ADDER : entity work.adder port map(
      a => a,
      b => b,
      alu_out => alu_out
    );



  --  Test Bench Statements
     tb : PROCESS
     BEGIN

        a <= B"0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0111_1010";
        b <= B"0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1011";

        wait for 100 ns; -- wait until global set/reset completes

        report "alu_out = " & integer'image(to_integer(signed(alu_out)));

        wait; -- will wait forever
     END PROCESS tb;
  --  End Test Bench 

  END;
```

I get report output:

```
Finished circuit initialization process.
at 100 ns: Note: alu_out = 0 (/testbench/).
```

If I don't initialize *result* signal I get Undefined. So problem is that I don't get
result in the end.

I use **iSim** and **Xilinx**.

Also if someone have some good links to some short and effective material on VHDL, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using signals for `result` and `result_ext` when you wanted their immediate value for that cycle of the process. Variables update immediately and you can access their values in the current cycle of the process.

Try this out, I think it fixes the problem you are having:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
           alu_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := (others => '0')
           );
end adder;

architecture Behavioral of adder is


begin

  process (a,b)
    variable result_ext:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(32 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    variable result:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
  begin
    result_ext := std_logic_vector(signed('0' & a) + signed('0' & b));
    result     := result_ext(result'left downto 0);

    alu_out <= result;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

As for reading material, the VHDL cookbook is not bad: [VHDL Cookbook](http://tams-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/vhdl/doc/cookbook/VHDL-Cookbook.pdf)

Comment: Just use numeric_std and the signed datatype.

Comment: That worked, also I got some indication that my testbench should have clock, and because of that this didn't work, I'll try it, and if it works, I'll update post :).

Answer (score 2):

Taking Peter's code and:

- updating for flexibility of width of inputs
- just `numeric_std`
- keeping the carry bit

gives this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is
    generic (width : integer := 32)
    Port ( a       : in  signed(width-1 downto 0);
           b       : in  signed(width-1 downto 0);
           alu_out : out signed(width downto 0) := (others => '0');
           );
end adder;

architecture synth of adder is
begin
  process (a,b)
  begin
    alu_out <= resize(a,alu_out'length) + b;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Yes, this is the better way of doing it. I wanted to show XoR the reason why their original code wasn't working due to using signals where variables were needed.

Comment: Well my ALU will have S, V, Z, N bits outputs, so I don't need something like this. I just put simplest example that failed, so I could put it in stackoverflow post. Also shouldn't we add with *a(a'left) & a* and not with *'0' & a*, because that way we lose sign.

Comment: @XoR: Good catch - quite right.  I shiuld've used the resize functions actually, then you don't have to think about it.  I'll update the post.